# How to count number of records by 'in' clause in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to run a sql query similar to:

`SELECT count(*) from WORDS where wordId in (4,5,6)`

How can I write this in Gorm? I know grails has `countBy*` but I can't pass multiple values like `[4,5,6]` into it.

should I just use `execute`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `rowCount` in the projections which counts the number of rows of the result. Note `id` as `Long`

```
Words.createCriteria().get {
  'in'('id', [4,5,6]*.toLong()) //or [4L, 5L, 6L]
  projections {
    rowCount()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [projections](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/createCriteria.html).

```
Words.createCriteria().get {
  'in'('id', [4,5,6])
  projections {
    count('id')
  }
}
```